# RegEx for checking character X places after another character

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I have done a very basic step which checks for the presence of one special character. The next step needs some advice as I want to be able to search for another special character starting from 1 places after finding #.

```
var reg = /#/;
alert(reg.test(string))
```

For example:

```
abc#.123     //invalid - as . is immediately after #
abc#12.3     //valid  - as . is more than 1 character after #
abc#abcd.23  //valid - as . is more than 1 character after #
a#123.12     //valid - as . is more than 1 character after #
a#12123124.12 //valid - as . is more than 1 character after #
abcd#1231.09  //valid - as . is more than 1 character after #
1.23#12312.01 //invalid - as . is before #
123#122.01#12 //invalid - as there is another# after .
```

So that gap between `#` and `.` should always be 1 or more characters with `#` always coming first.

Comment: Do you mean like `#..([!@#$%^&*()])` https://regex101.com/r/HZoWko/1

Comment: Try `^[^#.]*#.+\.`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/W6rA75/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could assert the start of the string `^`,  match not a `#` or `.` using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^#.]`, then match `#`.

Then repeat that part but then for the dot and then repeat that part until the end of the string:

```
^[^#.]*#[^.#]+\.[^.#]*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nlc2pl/1)

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[^#.]*#` Match 0+ times not `#` or `.` then match `#`
- `[^.#]+\.` Match 1+ times not `.` or `#` then match a dot
- `[^.#]*` Match 0+ times not `.` or `#`
- `$` End of string

```js
let pattern = /^[^#.]*#[^.#]+\.[^.#]*$/;
[
  "abc#.123",
  "abc#12.3",
  "abc#abcd.23",
  "a#123.12",
  "a#12123124.12",
  "abcd#1231.09",
  "1.23#12312.01",
  "123#122.01#12"
].forEach(s => console.log(s + ": " + pattern.test(s)))
```

Comment: Your regex matches `#..aa` where there is no gap between `#` and `.` and hence shouldn't match.

Comment: That is what the second pattern for. You say `and hence not match`, but in the question it does not state that in the gap there can be no dot, but `I want to be able to search for another special character starting from 1 places after finding #`

Comment: Everyone is right! It's entirely unclear from the original post how this should be interpreted.

Comment: Well, the main point OP is trying to make here is, that dot `.` shouldn't be immediately be followed by `#` and hence this post, but I'll let OP clarify on this.

Comment: updated the questions with scenarios, which hopefully will make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `/^[^\.#]*#[^\.#]+\.[^\.#]*$/`.

```
^  beginning of line anchor
 [^\.#]*  zero or more characters other than . and #
        #  literal # character
         [^\.#]+  one or more characters other than . and #
                \.  literal . character
                  [^\.#]*  one or more characters other than . and #
                         $  EOL
```

In general, use `/^[^\.#]*#[^\.#]{5,}\.[^#\.]*$/` if you want a specifically-sized minimum gap (in this case, 5 or more), or `{5}` if you want the gap to be exactly 5.

```js
var reg = /^[^\.#]*#[^\.#]+\.[^\.#]*$/;

[
  "abc#.123",      // invalid - as . is immediately after #
  "abc#12.3",      // valid - as . is more than 1 character after #
  "abc#abcd.23",   // valid - as . is more than 1 character after #
  "a#123.12",      // valid - as . is more than 1 character after #
  "a#12123124.12", // valid - as . is more than 1 character after #
  "abcd#1231.09",  // valid - as . is more than 1 character after #
  "1.23#12312.01", // invalid - as . is before #
  "123#122.01#12", // invalid - as there is another# after .
].forEach(test => console.log(reg.test(test)));
```

Comment: This is matching `abc#..`

Comment: Thanks for the note--OP updated requirements and I hadn't seen any message about it until now. See discussion in the fourth bird's answer for previous ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex for ensuring the first `#` in your string is followed by a dot `.` where gap between `#` and `.` is one or more characters,

```
^[^#]*#[^.]+\.
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` - Start of string
- `[^#]*` - Zero or more characters other than `#` and if you want dot to also not appear before a `#` then you can change it to `[^#.]*`
- `#` - Match the first `#` character
- `[^.]+` - Match one or more characters other than dot
- `\.` - Match a literal dot

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uvembf/1/)**

JS Code demo,

```js
const arr = ['abc#.123','abc#12.3','abc#abcd.23','a#123.12','a#..dd']

arr.forEach(s => console.log(s + " --> " + /^[^#]*#[^.]+\./.test(s)))
```